# Uniform convergence with uniform bound on second derivatives implies $C^1$ convergence.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I am having some difficulties proving this fact, since I am not very familiar with this kind of exercises.

Let $f_n : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a sequence of $C^\infty$ functions.
Suppose $f_n$ converge to some $f$ uniformly on compact intervals and that $f_n ''$ are uniformly bounded. Then $f_n$ converge to $f$ in $C^1$ on compact intervals.

I have to prove that $\underset{x\in [-T,T]}{\sup} |f'_n(x) -f'(x)| \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$, but I don't quite know how to proceed. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is there any textbook or reference which proves this or a similar statement?

Answer (score 2):

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{\infty}^{K}$ defined by :

$$ \Vert f \Vert_{\infty}^{K} = \sup \limits_{x \in K} \vert f(x) \vert $$

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. For all $n$, $\varphi := f_{n}-f$ is twice differentiable, with $\varphi$ and $\varphi''$ bounded on $K$. An [inequality](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Landau-KolmogorovConstants.html) due to Landau gives you :

$$ \Vert \varphi' \Vert_{\infty}^{K} \leq 2 \big( \Vert \varphi \Vert_{\infty}^{K} \Vert \varphi'' \Vert_{\infty}^{K} \big)^{\frac{1}{2}} $$

Since $(f_{n}'')_{n}$ are uniformly bounded, there exists a constant $C > 0$ such that :

$$ \Vert f_{n}'-f' \Vert_{\infty}^{K} \leq C \big( \Vert f_{n}-f \Vert_{\infty}^{K} \big)^{\frac{1}{2}} $$

Which gives you that $(f_{n}')_{n}$ converges uniformly to $f'$ on every compact. It proves that $(f_{n})$ converges to $f$ in $\mathcal{C}^{1}$ norm on compact intervals since the norm is : $\displaystyle \Vert f \Vert_{\infty ~ , ~ \mathcal{C}^{1}}^{K} = \sup \limits_{x \in K} \big( \vert f(x) \vert + \vert f'(x) \vert \big)$.

Comment: How can we guarantee that $f'$ and $f''$ exist? Without this, $\varphi$ cannot be twice differentiable. As I know, the uniform convergence $f_n \to f$ just guarantees that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @JaeYoungLee You can use $\varphi = f_n - f_m$ instead and work with Cauchy sequences.

Comment: @PratyushSarkar, agreed and thanks, but we also need to apply https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3356315/uniform-convergence-of-the-derivatives-means-convergence-of-the-function to have $f_n' \to f'$ --- the above proof with $\varphi = f_n = f_m$ will show $(f_n')_n$ is uniformly Cauchy so uniformly converges, but it doesn't show the convergence towards $f'$.

Comment: I also think rather than $\mathcal{C}^\infty$, twice differentiability of each $f_n$ is enough to prove the statement.

Comment: @JaeYoungLee Fix a compact set $K$. We know $f_n$ converges uniformly on $K$ to some $f$. Now, doing what I said shows the sequence $f_n'$ converges uniformly on $K$ to some differentiable function $g$ (it seems you agree with this). Now there is a theorem (for example Theorem 9 in Chapter 4 of Real Mathematical Analysis by Pugh) that these properties imply that in fact $f$ is differentiable and moreover $f' = g$.

I agree that $C^2$ is enough.

Comment: @PratyushSarkar I think we were on the same page. You meant $f_n' \to g'$ on $K$ for some differentiable function $g$ (which I agree). Then, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3356315/uniform-convergence-of-the-derivatives-means-convergence-of-the-function, which is a bit famous theorem from Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Rudin, shows $f' = g$.

Comment: @PratyushSarkar I meant $f' = g'$ at the last.

Comment: @PratyushSarkar Theorem 9 in Chapter 4 of Real Mathematical Analysis by Pugh -- see https://smartmanmaths.files.wordpress.com/2017/11/real-mathematical-analysis.pdf -- shows $f$ is differentiable, but it doesn't show $f' = g'$. But anyway, thank you for the theorem.

Comment: @JaeYoungLee Yes it seems we were saying the same thing. I thought you were saying it doesn't work. I didn't say anything more in my first comment since this theorem is standard.

I really do mean that a priori $f_n'$ uniformly converges to some $g$ (Not $g'$. I shouldn't have said differentiable g). Then by the theorem, $f$ is also differentiable and $f' = g$.

Also, I agree that technically the theorem in Pugh's book did not say $f' = g$, but if you see the proof, they prove that.

Comment: @PratyushSarkar all agreed!