# uniform convergence of the derivatives means convergence of the function

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

There is one step in the proof the following proof that I would love to understand the intuition.

Theorem 14.7.1.

Let $[a,b]$ be an interval, and for every integer $n \geq 1$, let $f_n : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function whose derivative $f_n^{\prime} : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Suppose that the derivatives $f_n^{\prime}$ converge uniformly to a function $g : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Suppose also there exists a point $x_0$ such that the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} f_n(x_0)$ exists. Then the functions $f_n$ converge uniformly to a differentiable function f, and the derivative of f equals g.

I don't understand the intuition of how g is defined below. More specifically. What I don't understand is why we have the term $L - \int_{[a,x_0]} g$ in the proof below. I have checked that it does work, but I don't understand why it works.

Proof:

[image]

Comment: $g$ is not really "defined" is it? It is what by assumptions the $f'_n$ converge to. Formally I would think about how to get this $f$ though, is that is must satisfy two things we want first $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x_0) = f(x_0)= L$, so there must be an L. But we also need $f'(x) = g(x)$. So since $g$ is continuous we can infer by the Fundamental Theorem of calculus to get $g(x) = d/dx \int_{[c,x]} g(x)dx$. Now you only need to find what a reasonable "c" might be. But this is determined by the first condition.

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what I thought. Thank you for the clarification.