# I wonder why the author assumed $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges pointwise to a function $f$ on $[a,b]$. ("Calculus I" by Shizuo Miyazima)

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

I am reading "Calculus I" (in Japanese) by Shizuo Miyazima.

> Theorem 6.5
> Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of continuous functions on $[a,b]$.
> Suppose $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly to $f$.
> Then, $f$ is also continuous on $[a,b]$ and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b} f_n(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx$$ holds.

> Theorem 6.8
> Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of $C^1$ functions on $[a,b]$.
> Suppose $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges pointwise to a function $f$ on $[a,b]$.
> Suppose $(f'_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly to a function $g$ on $[a,b]$.
> Then, $f$ is a $C^1$ function and $f'=g$ holds.

I wonder why the author assumed $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges pointwise to a function $f$ on $[a,b]$ in Theorem 6.8.

Suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(c)=d$ for some $c\in [a,b]$.
Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{c}^{x} f'_n(t)dt=\int_{c}^{x}g(t)dt$ holds by Theorem 6.5.
Since $\int_{c}^{x} f'_n(t)dt=f_n(x)-f_n(c)$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(c)=d$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\int_{c}^{x}g(t)dt+d.$
So, $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges pointwise to the function $\int_{c}^{x}g(t)dt+d$ on $[a,b]$.
So, I want to rewrite Theorem 6.8 as follows:

> Theorem 6.8'
> Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of $C^1$ functions on $[a,b]$.
> Suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(c)=d$ for some $c\in [a,b]$.
> Suppose $(f'_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly to a function $g$ on $[a,b]$.
> Then, $f$ is a $C^1$ function and $f'=g$ holds.

Is Theorem 6.8' right?

Comment: Yes, your version Theorem 6.8' is correct, and well-known, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/214218/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1194164/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3356315/42969

Comment: Now the problem is you haven't defined $f$ in your reformulation.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you very much for your information and your links.

Comment: @BrunoB Thank you very much for your correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, theorem 6.8' is not correct.

In fact, it is also not incorrect. What it is is the dreaded *"not well defined"*.

In particular, the last sentence of your theorem states that $f$ is a $C^1$ function, but that is the *first* appearance of the symbol $f$. Since $f$ is not defined previously, the statement "$f$ has this and that property" is not a well defined statement.

Comment: 5xum, Thank you very much for your answer. I edited my answer.

Comment: @tchappyha: No, you edited your *question.* That is usually a bad thing, as it may invalidate given answers.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you very much for your comment. I reedited my question.